# Elasticsearch incorrect document count after `scan` & `scroll` and then `refresh` & `flush`

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I use `scan` and `scroll` to reindex from old_index to new_index. Right after the reindex completes, I do a `refresh` and `flush`, hoping that the data will persist into the disk. I then immediately read the document counts of both indices. The new index will usually have zero documents. I have to repeatedly read the document counts in a loop (with a 1-second pause in each iteration). Only after 20 seconds or so, I will see equal document counts. (The refresh rate of both indices were set to 30 seconds).

From my understanding, calling either `refresh` or `flush`, I should see the actual document counts. But it is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ***Elasticsearch1.6*** You can use:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index/_flush/synced
```

to `sync` `flush` execution to be finished.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But [the official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-synced-flush.html#indices-synced-flush) does not mention that this api will block even though the API name suggests so. **A synced flush performs a normal flush, then adds a generated unique marker (sync_id) to all shards**. From my understanding, a `synced flush` is merely a `flush` + a marker.

Comment: @foresightyj You can check [Synced Flush Api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-synced-flush.html#_synced_flush_api) to get more details.

Comment: Yes. I did read them (`refresh`, `flush`, `synced flush`) a few times. I am not concerned if all data is persisted. I just want to be sure that the new index has the same number of data as the old index (be it in the memory or the translog). Those three apis' documentations do not mention if they are synchronous or asynchronous. From the results I observed, I guess `refresh` and `flush` are asynchronous and `synced flush`, as only the name suggests, is synchronous.

Comment: originally I thought `wait_if_ongoing` in the `flush` api was the way to make it synchronous, but a closer look at the doc suggests that it will only block until it can start flushing, but will not wait until the flushing completes.